# Reactjs material icons in css

Tags: css, reactjs, google-material-icons

I have the following materials-icon package installed:

```
@material-ui/icons@4.9.1
```

I need to set the 'content' value for one of classes, in my CSS file, to the down arrow. How do I do this?

Comment: I think you need to override the existing styles in order to do that. have you tried using !important?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Material UI icons from `@material-ui/icons@4.9.1` are exported as React components so you cannot use them in CSS.

But you have few options.

1. Include the material icons font and use that. More info [here](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons) and [here](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/)

Check the [codepen](https://codepen.io/estelle/pen/MwvOjd)

Once you have included the font in your page you can use it in CSS like this

```
p::after, 
div::after {
  content: "face";
  color: blue;
}
```

2. But I dont like importing the entire fonts file just to have a single icon. So this is what I used to do.

Get the svg of the icon. Inspect the icon from material ui icons page, get the svg code and create a new svg file with the copied html and place it in your project.

[image]

Once you have the svg file, in your CSS use it like this

```
.download:before {
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
  background-image: url('path-to-svg-folder/download.svg');
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}
```

NB: if you dont want to have a svg file you can use the data url method and include the entire svg in your CSS file.